# OData Client side proxy with bearer token

Tags: c#, odata

So I'm new to OData and I need to use a vendor OData V4 service which requires a bearer token in the header authorization.  I'm trying to create strongly typed classes for entities and attributes which will give IntelliSense support in Microsoft Visual Studio.  I'm following the below example but I'm lost when it comes to adding the authorization in the header. Can't find anything on MSDN or google. Can someone please help or advice if it is even possible?  I'm using VS 2017 Enterprise.

[Example](https://www.netwoven.com/2018/05/29/how-to-create-client-side-odata-proxy-dll-for-microsoft-dynamics-365-for-finance-and-operations-ax/)

Answer (score 0):

The generated `DataServiceContext` has an event called `SendingRequest2` that exposes the actual HTTP requests (one of the properties of the event args) right before they are sent. You can add a handler to that event and manipulate the HTTP requests to add the appropriate header. Something like:

```
context.SendingRequest2 += (s, e) =>
{
    e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Authorization", token);
};
```

Comment: Is that in Odata V4 because I can't find it?

Comment: OData V4 is the protocol version which has nothing to do with it. Yes it is in the current version of the OData Client library and has been for a while. The is the library that is used by the “OData V4 Client Code Generator” template in VS.